# Why is the rotation gizmo not working in 2.74?

Tags: transforms

When I left-click using the Translate or Scale gizmo it translates or scales according to axis, as expected; however, when I left-click close to the colored circles of the rotation gizmo, it doesn't rotate the object and just moves the 3D cursor.

Is it a bug? If yes, is there a standard way of reported such bugs (I've seen the blender.org/forum is closed)

Comment: If its not working for you that doesn't mean there is a bug. Can you add a screen shot of the transformation panel or attach the blend file?

Comment: bug reports should [go to the bug-tracker](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Process/Bug_Reports) but not this time :)

Answer (score 6):

It's not a bug, you can imagine this widget is something that's used by an incredible amount of people and is heavily tested. But this issue has cropped up from time to time and depends heavily on the graphics card drivers used.

Try [Setting "Selection" in User Preferences System Tab from "Auto" to "OpenGL Select" or "OpenGL Occlusion Queries"](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?260454-Issues-selecting-the-3d-manipulator-arrows&p=2759960&viewfull=1#post2759960)

The keyboard shortcuts for the transform tools are G, (grab), R (rotate), and S (scale), often they are more convenient, in combination with their follow up keys `x, y, z` to select the axis..

Comment: thank you zefii. "OpenGL Select" didn't work, but "OpenGL Occlusion Queries" did ;-)

Comment: I'd like to say that I just ran into this issue where my rotation widget was stuck on Z axis constraint regardless of what axis I was trying to move in 2.79b. Oddly it had worked before and just decided it was tired of cooperating. Changing the selection from 'Automatic' to OpenGL Occlusion Queries though solved the issue.