# Blender 2.75b fails to start on Windows 10

Tags: 3d-view, command-line, windows

I am trying to install / start Blender on Windows 10.  It shows the console window (but no text in it) and never shows the application window.  The console window never disappears either.  This is odd as I have the same blender running on 2 other Windows 10 machines.  I've downloaded both the MSI and the zip file.  Any suggestions on how to debug this?  Is there a command line flag that will log application progress?

Comment: Depends on what hardware are you trying to run it. If it's a phone (extreme case) it won't work.

Comment: Lenovo X1 Carbon.  Corei7  Intel 5000 graphics.

Comment: Yes Intel integrated graphics have been always problems, probably driver issues. There are many threads here with gui glitches or freezing such: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33802/cant-select-vertices-loop-cut-doesnt-work. Though people were able to run Blender at least. If you won't be able to find driver that will work you might consider filling a bug report https://developer.blender.org/ because you surely qualify the minimal system specs.

Comment: I finally wiped the machine down to the bare hardware using the recovery partition.  Loaded all the updates from M$ and re-installed.  Blender now works.  Kind of extreme, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

So the real answer here seems to be in Windows and the drivers.  The only solution I've found is that I can re-install the Operating System to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem also in windows 10 with 2.77a though I managed to solve this by simply opening the app as administrator. You can then define to open the application always in the same way.

hope this help